# Can Sharekit, GoogleMaps open sources used in making iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, google-maps, xcode4

i am using sharekit open source for facebook/twitter sharing , and also Google maps for displaying the maps and all that stuff like driving directions, current location, annotations etc etc in my iPhone application . i just want to know about its acceptance on itunes by apple.

Does Apple Approve share kit?
Can google maps be used in iPhone??
 Please give me any idea about it

Thanks

Comment: Of course they can, there are endless examples of Google maps being used. About Sharekit, I would advise to use facebook's iOS SDK directly and not be dependent on anything else to work with facebook because it's much more dynamic and has less backwards compatibility.

Comment: I've used ShareKit times ago without problems, but as @stavash said i suggest you to use the official SDKs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though ShareKit is hopelessly dated and not updated since ages (last update over a year ago), there still is no reason for Apple to not approve your app when using it. Personally, I would strongly advise to not use ShareKit as it is super buggy and did not keep up with the latest changes on Twitter's API but that is your choice.

Google Maps also is not a show-stopper at all. As said by others, there are many Apps on the AppStore using it.

Comment: This is not true, sharekit has a big community behind it and gets updated regularly. https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit
What you mean is the initial project from Nate Weiner which hasn't been updated for a long time.

Comment: @yinkou you are correct, I meant the original project. Still I also have had a really bad experience with the existing forks and hence decided to refrain from ShareKit altogether. After all, if using Twitter and Facebook is what you need, I would recommend using the original FB-Framework and DETwitterComposer to achieve a slick, flexible and well functioning experience.